# jS Copy Function don't work even if the text get selected and defined?

Tags: javascript

Hi any idea how to make this Copy text function work as it should ?
I put an arrow function before the select still no solution.
thank you.

```js
function paste() {

  let toSelect = ('Select text!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! ');
  console.log(toSelect);
 
  toSelect.select();
  toSelect.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
  document.execCommand('copy');
  alert("Copied the text: " + toSelect);

}
```

```html
<button onclick=paste(); type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error I see is that you are trying to use the `HTMLInputElement.select()` method on a string which is not allowed. The variable `toSelect` isn't an `<input>` or `<textarea>` element therefore the `select()` method won't be invoked.

The `select()` method selects all the text in a `<textarea>` element or in an `<input>` element that includes a text field. [HTMLInputElement.select() - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select)

```js
function paste() {
  const text = document.getElementById("text");
  const output = document.getElementById("paste-output");
  text.select();
  text.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
  document.execCommand('copy');
  alert("Copied the text: " + text.value);
  output.textContent = text.value;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text">Some text to copied</textarea>
<button onclick=paste(); type="button">Click Me!</button>
<span id="paste-output"></span>
```

Comment: so you can't run the select() on an array item ?

Comment: `HTMLInputElement.select()` can only be invoked on `<input>` or `<textarea>` tags. So if you have an array of `<input>` or `<textarea>` items, then yes you could use the `select()` method on those elements.

Comment: is there any alternative then, to select a string item ? or is it only the select method I that works only on <input> <textarea> ?I  cannot change my all HTML structure to <input>, its a static html divs that I want them to get copied on selection. but since this select is not going to work any alt for this.?

Comment: Unfortunately, the `select()` method will not work on strings. It only works for `<input>` or `<textarea>` elements. If you post a new question with your HTML and what you would like to investigate or find out, feel free to post the link here in the comments and I'll have a look to potentially answer it for you.

Comment: @Complex86 Look up the Clipboard API.

Comment: thanks I have security concerns with the Clipboard API ,but I might find a way to do it by appended a input in the back ground and take the text from that input but I need to work on this I want this project to be API free also when it coms to core functionality .